# Django item IDs are messed up

Tags: sql, django

Is there a way to clean up/recalibrate ID numbers for a table? After editing and deleting some objects there are gaps in my ID's.

ex: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,21,22,23,24,25,29,30,31...`

Django just adds new items incrementally after the highest ID, and the gaps are causing problems. I am using Postregsql.

Comment: What are you trying to do that means that gaps are causing problems? There's probably a better solution than trying to manually manage ids.

Comment: Absolutely. I can't think of a possible reason why gaps should cause you problems.

Comment: I guess I'm sorting by them, and it feels like there shouldn't be gaps in the list. It's not necessarily hindering my app from working. Is it okay to have staggered id numbers like this? The feeling I'm getting from searching for solutions to this is that it's not a problem, and people generally ignore the ID numbers. Is that so?

Comment: This response is a relief. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First approach:

you can create a new model field `item_number`. Then, keep this new field 'by hand':

- On save(): If this save is a insert, you should calculate `item_number` as maximum of `item_number` over table. Remember that this operation can cause locks.

Perhaps, the most light way to do this is:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
       self.item_number = Entry.objects.latest('item_number') + 1 if 
                          Entry.objects.exists() else 0
    super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

- On delete(): you should renumerate all models with a `item_numer` grather than deleted.

Here a sample:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    myModel.objecte.filter( item_number__gt = self.item_number).update(
            item_number=F('item_number') - 1 )
```

**Both methods may cause big locks in tables. Remember that a atomic operation is needed, you should use [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/).**